# Binding whole object on click (primeng autocomplete)?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, primeng

I have this array:

```
[{
    "user_id": 101,
    "user_name": "John"
},
{
    "user_id": 101,
    "user_name": "Ganesh"
},
{
    "user_id": 101,
    "user_name": "Irfan"
}]
```

In my HTML I have this:

```
<p-autoComplete placeholder="User Search..." field="user_name" [suggestions]="suggestionList"  (completeMethod)="userSearch($event)"></p-autoComplete>
```

My question is can I select item from autocomplete and get whole object with user_id and user_name?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can get whole object. Add `[(ngModel)]="selection"` and define 'selection' in component with the same type as type of your suggestions array.